# Need to sum every 7 columns in Excel worksheet

Tags: excel, sum, offset

I have a data set which has 1 ROW and 365 COLUMNS of data.  I need to sum the data for every block of 7 columns which I will put into different rows or columns. I realize that 7 does not divide into 365 evenly and am not sure how to account for this or if the correct formula can do this automatically.

B6 is the first cell with data and NB6 is the last cell with data.  I'm entering my formula in B14 and can proceed across 51 more columns or rows (doesn't matter).

So far I have been able to successfully sum the first 7 columns with the following formula:

=SUM(OFFSET($B$6,(COLUMN()-COLUMN($NB$6))*0,0,1,7))

However, when copying the formula into successive columns or rows, the formula continues to provide the same value instead of sums for the following 7 days blocks.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this formula:

```
=SUM(INDEX($6:$6,((ROW(1:1)-1)*7)+2):INDEX($6:$6,((ROW(1:1)*7)+1)))
```

And drag down.

For columns use:

```
=SUM(INDEX($6:$6,((COLUMN(A:A)-1)*7)+2):INDEX($6:$6,((COLUMN(A:A)*7)+1)))
```

And copy across.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help Scott, the formulas work great!

Comment: @GGB then you may have numbers as text, because I just went through them all and they are all spot on.

Comment: FOLLOW UP:  Is there a way to account for the fact that the last block of the 365, will actually be a block of 8 instead of 7?  Thanks!

Comment: @GGB on that **last formula** just change the +1 at the end to a +2 and it will pick it up.   I can change all the formulas to deal with it but it would be easier to change only the last formula manually.

Comment: Scott, I changed up the last formula to accommodate differing column numbers on various similar worksheets; everything works great.  Thanks again for your time and help!